# ActionBarSherlock menu items background

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using `ActionBarSherlock` in my Project, is it possible to override overflow menu items backgrounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the theme in your directory to try and override the ActionBarSherlock
For example to use the DarkActionBar with a light dropdown list:

```
<style name="YourAppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListView.DropDown</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListView.DropDown</item> 
</style>
```